# Build or-tools 7.1 with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, or-tools

I am trying to build or-tools version 7.1 with cmake (3.16.3) in Linux Mint 20 Ulyana (based on ubuntu focal)

I am following the instructions from here https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/f3fd201e68cf75b7720ff5c3cadc599a1d02b54b/cmake/README.md

First i run `cmake -H. -Bbuild -G "Unix Makefiles"` but this failed because dependencies not found so i replaced it with `cmake -H. -Bbuild -G "Unix Makefiles" -DBUILD_DEPS=ON`

But after a while got the following errors

```
[ 55%] No test step for 'Cbc_project'
[ 66%] Completed 'Cbc_project'
[100%] Built target Cbc_project
-- Building Cbc: ...DONE
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at ortools/constraint_solver/CMakeLists.txt:57 (add_dependencies):
  The dependency target "absl::container" of target
  "ortools_constraint_solver" does not exist.


CMake Error at ortools/glop/CMakeLists.txt:50 (add_dependencies):
  The dependency target "absl::container" of target "ortools_glop" does not
  exist.


CMake Error at ortools/linear_solver/CMakeLists.txt:54 (add_dependencies):
  The dependency target "absl::container" of target "ortools_linear_solver"
  does not exist.


CMake Error at ortools/sat/CMakeLists.txt:60 (add_dependencies):
  The dependency target "absl::container" of target "ortools_sat" does not
  exist.


CMake Error at ortools/constraint_solver/CMakeLists.txt:33 (target_compile_options):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/constraint_solver/CMakeLists.txt:45 (target_compile_definitions):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/constraint_solver/CMakeLists.txt:20 (target_include_directories):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/constraint_solver/CMakeLists.txt:45 (target_compile_definitions):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/constraint_solver/CMakeLists.txt:20 (target_include_directories):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/glop/CMakeLists.txt:30 (target_compile_options):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/glop/CMakeLists.txt:40 (target_compile_definitions):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/glop/CMakeLists.txt:19 (target_include_directories):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/glop/CMakeLists.txt:40 (target_compile_definitions):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/glop/CMakeLists.txt:19 (target_include_directories):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/linear_solver/CMakeLists.txt:32 (target_compile_options):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/linear_solver/CMakeLists.txt:43 (target_compile_definitions):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/linear_solver/CMakeLists.txt:20 (target_include_directories):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/linear_solver/CMakeLists.txt:43 (target_compile_definitions):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/linear_solver/CMakeLists.txt:20 (target_include_directories):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/sat/CMakeLists.txt:34 (target_compile_options):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/sat/CMakeLists.txt:47 (target_compile_definitions):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/sat/CMakeLists.txt:20 (target_include_directories):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/sat/CMakeLists.txt:47 (target_compile_definitions):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


CMake Error at ortools/sat/CMakeLists.txt:20 (target_include_directories):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:absl::container,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>

  Target "absl::container" not found.


-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can also use CMake GUI. That way you can see all available options. Alternatively, you can open CMakeCache.txt which may have been generated.

Comment: Also, hope you are following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/cpp/source_linux)

Comment: @Anastasios Loumpas:  Your cmake instructions: Old (2018) . **New** (2021) = https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/cmake/README.md#deps ..... Minimum is `abseil-cpp, protobuf >= 3.12, (bazel?)` .............. → `cmake .. -DUSE_SCIP=OFF -DUSE_COINOR=OFF`

Comment: Thank you @KnudLarsen i was looking on the old ones because i was looking on 7.1 branch exactly. I will take a look on the new instructions

Comment: No guaranty the new ones (v9.1  https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases and the current github version) are easier to build. I failed with this https://github.com/google/or-tools

Answer (score 0):

CMake was not fully implemented in 7.1.

Why stay on 7.1? Why not use make in 7.1 ?

Comment: Yes i have seen that it is not fully supported on 7.1. We are still on 7.1 because we are using the software on a production project and we have not test the latest versions for performance. Last time we checked the 7.3 through 7.6 we had lowest performance on routing so we stick to 7.1 for now. I want to use CMake in order to simplify the maintenance of our makefile.

Comment: I think this should go in the comment section of the question instead of being an answer. (it is primarily asking for more details)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is abseil-cpp master have dropped the `absl::container` CMake target.

To summary in v7.1 the CMake based build when building all deps using `-DBUILD_DEPS=ON` will use abseil-cpp master branch
ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/f3fd201e68cf75b7720ff5c3cadc599a1d02b54b/cmake/dependencies/CMakeLists.txt#L50-L59

But since v7.1 release the `absl::container` target has been dropped

> The empty absl::container target has been removed from the CMake build. This target had no effect and references to this target in user code can safely be removed.
> see: https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/releases/tag/20210324.2

A possible workaround would be to change the TAG `master` to `20200923.3`  in `cmake/dependencies/CMakeLists.txt#L50-L59`

**BUT** as Laurent said we strongly recommend you to use the last stable version v9.1

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions i will have a look on that and also try to disable some non needed dependencies and report back my findings. I dont think that i can totally disable the abseil-cpp dependency and still routing library with constraint solver will compile and run successfully. Am i right?